# drf - how to access field of parent serializer in child serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models 
models.py

```
class First(models.Model):
    is_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
class Second(models.Model):
    some_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   
class Third(models.Model):
    first = models.ForeignKey(First, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    second = models.ForeignKey(Second, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class SecondSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field = serializers.BooleanField()
    is_available = serializers.BooleanField() # field from models.First    

class ThirdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    second = SecondSerializer()
```

views.py

```
class ThirdViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    .........
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Third.objects.select_related('first', 'second')
```

I have to send the response through ThirdSerializer but First.is_available should be sent in SecondSerializer. How can I achieve that?

Comment: A `Second` object can be related to many `Third` objects, so which one do you want to use?

Comment: I can't change the structure, so I'm sending third object which contains second object. Second object should have the field of first object @BrianDestura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a property is_available to second object and pass it to serializer.

```
class SecondSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field = serializers.BooleanField()
    is_available = serializers.BooleanField()

class ThirdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    second = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_second(self, obj):
        second = obj.second
        second.is_available = obj.first.is_available
        return SecondSerializer(instance=second).data
```